# update a div after deleting file, my ajax does not take my href id with mootools?

Tags: ajax, mootools, href

I am trying to archive this task, I got a script2.php where I list files from a directory and for every file there is a delete link, but when I press the delete link, my ajax mootools does not take the id of the href, it shows a message of undefined, all what I want to do is a similar effect like [this](http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/mootools-record-delete.php) but simple,

the question is how can I archieve that my mootools ajax take the id of href for pass to my deletefile.php?? I am updating the div when I delete but first that takes this event for deleting the file.

this is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEvent('domready', function() {

           $$('a.delete').addEvent('click', function() {
               alert("Here I am");

              //alert($$('a').id); 



    //         var newDelete = new Request({
    //           method: 'GET',
    //           url: 'deletefile.php',
    //           data: 'identifier='+identifier,
    //           onRequest: function() {$('divShowmessage').innerHTML="Cargando...";},
    //           onSuccess: function(texto, xmlrespuesta) {alert($$('a').id);},
    //           onFailure: function(){alert('Error!');}
    //           }).send();

           });

        });


    </script>

    <?php


    $ruta = "./uploadedfiles/";
    $directory = dir($ruta);
    $types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'txt', 'gif', 'png', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'xlsx', 'pptx');
    $identifier = "";


    while ($file = $directory->read()) {
        $division = explode(".", $file);
        $extension = end($division);
        $identifier = $archivo;


       if(in_array($extension, $types)){

<div id="delete">
 echo $file . "&nbsp;<a id=\"". $identifier."\" href=\"#\">Delete</a><br>";
    //echo $archivo . "&nbsp;<a id=\"". $identificador."\" href=deletefile.php?file=" . urlencode($file) .">Delete</a><br>";
          //echo $file. "<a id=refresh href=# >Delete</a><br> ";

</div>

       }

    }

    $directory->close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$$('a')` inside of the `addEvent` method is not the right way of doing it.

What you're trying to do in the code above is get the `id` from an **element collection** (array).

What you want to od is do `this.get('id')`

Also, you want to stop the event, with `event.stop()`

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/gSf2q/

Comment: but I am trying to get names of files for removing how can you identify each removed file? I already edit the code <div id="delete"> (a.delete) but this is for all the elements inside a delete div

Comment: I already right thanks for all your solution works well I still do not understand what does event.stop and console.log;